# Kafka console consumer get partition

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using Kafka console consumer to consume messages from the topic with several partitions:

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic events
```

But it prints only message body. Is there any way to print record metadata or partition number as well? Cause I want to know where the message сonsumed from.

I've explored console consumer doc http://documentation.kamanja.org/_static/command-ref/kafka-console-consumer.pdf but didn't find any related properties.

**UPDATED:**

So, as I see the only solution is to override *DefaultMessageFormatter.class* (we can set it by running kafka console consumer with *--formatter* property) and add custom logic that prints record metadata in the #writeTo(..) method.

Comment: From java consumer it is possible .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider using a more powerful Kafka command line consumer like kafkacat https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/blob/master/README.md

For example, the following command will print the topic, partition, offset and message payload/value for each message consumed:

`kcat -b <broker> -C -t <topic> -f '%t %p @ %o: %s\n'`

Answer (score 11):

I found I was successfully able to subscribe to a topic and output the key and partition using this --properties flag like so:

```
kafka-console-consumer \
  --topic <some-topic> \
  --bootstrap-server :9092 \
  --from-beginning \
  --property print.key=true \
  --property print.partition=true
```

It gave me an output like this:

```
Partition:0 "3" {"id": 2}
```

Comment: According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-431%3A+Support+of+printing+additional+ConsumerRecord+fields+in+DefaultMessageFormatter, the option was officially added in 2.7, but existed undocumented before that.

Comment: This doesn't print the partition for me even though I use the 2.12 version

Answer (score 4):

For kafka 9 there is nothing out-of-the-box that can print you that info.

According to the code, message formatter gets key and value only.

```
try {
    formatter.writeTo(msg.key, msg.value, System.out)
}
```

`--property print.key=true` allows to print message key.

In kafka 10 there is one more useful param `print.timestamp`

Comment: in Kafka sources, I guess